# SVN filesystem structure?

Tags: svn, version-control

I want to understand the default layout for SVN repos.  My understanding is that this is the layout:

```
/trunk
     /Project1
     /Project2
/branches
     /Project1
     /Project2
/tags
     /Project1
     /Project2
```

But a repo doesn't have to follow that layout. How can I determine the layout of an existing svn repo?

Comment: `svn ls --depth infinity svn://your.repo.here/` would tell you more than you wanted to know about it. Or just install TortoiseSVN (on windows)..

Comment: There is no default repository layout in SVN. There are 'suggested' ones: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.projects.chooselayout

Comment: I think the "default" layout (or the most widely adopted layout) of SVN you understand is incorrectly.  Normally there is a `PROJECT` directory, and under that, we have `trunk/`, `branches/`, `tags/` for that PROJECT

Comment: Interesting how with SVN the structure is reflected in the work tree, whereas with git the structure is internal and the work tree just has a single instance (or do I mis-understand?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repository layout in SVN is completely up to its users - it does not have to follow any conventions, unless explicitly enforced with sophisticated hooks (and that is not very typical).

You can use the `svn list` command to explore svn remotely, i.e. without checking it out:

```
svn list http://myserver/svn/repo
```

It can be also used recursively, or produce XML output:

```
-R [--recursive]         : descend recursively, same as --depth=infinity
--depth ARG              : limit operation by depth ARG ('empty', 'files',
                          'immediates', or 'infinity')
--xml                    : output in XML
```

Besides that, you can see the state as of specified revision. Following command gives you complete list of options:

```
svn list --help
```